# Security warning in the console of BrowserWindow (electron ^9.2.0)

Tags: javascript, electron

I am new to **electron** and I am getting this in the console (of DevTools) of every `BrowserWindow` I open:

```
webFrame.executeJavaScript was called without worldSafeExecuteJavaScript enabled. This is considered unsafe. worldSafeExecuteJavaScript will be enabled by default in Electron 12.
```

I am also getting one more security warning and that is:

```
Electron Security Warning (Insecure Content-Security-Policy) This renderer process has either no Content Security
    Policy set or a policy with "unsafe-eval" enabled. This exposes users of
    this app to unnecessary security risks.
```

I don't know what exactly I am doing wrong...!!

[This is my console window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSK0V.png)

[This is my package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2u6M.png)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### webFrame.executeJavaScript and contextIsolation

Add the following setting to your BrowserWindow in main.js

```js
webPreferences { worldSafeExecuteJavaScript: true, contextIsolation: true }
```

For reference, see:

- https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#class-browserwindow

### Insecure Content-Security-Policy

Add the following to the head of your index.html and any other html pages if you are loading locally

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self'">
```

For reference, see:

- https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security#6-define-a-content-security-policy
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP

Comment: The warning will only disappear if you also set contextIsolation to true.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting this is because you don't have a CSP header. A CSP header makes sure you only load whatever that you want to load (no scripts from other sites, etc.). This is a huge hit for security

1. First, add a CSP policy, like this one:

   ```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'">
   ```
2. See electron [documentation on security.](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/security)